# Rails rake assets:precompile produces hundreds of jquery.ui.datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment, jquery-ui-datepicker

I noticed that `rake assets:precompile` takes extremely long on my production server, at least 10+ minutes. I went to take a look at my public/assets folder and I noticed that there were hundreds of variations of jquery.ui.datepicker..

This is what my terminal shows...

```
$ dir public/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker
Display all 280 possibilities? (y or n)
```

It ranges from jquery.ui.datepicker-856....css through hundreds of combinations to jquery.ui.datepicker-zh-TW.js.gz.

I don't know if all these files are necessary, but could this be part of the reason why it's taking so long to precompile my assets? Also I only started having this issue when I added this line to my **production.rb**

`config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )`